# Changing ASP <connectionStrings> parameters in web.config needs a recompile?

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, web-config, connection-pooling

Since my site goes very slow, I googled and I found that the problem could be in the connection pool. 
So I would change my connection string from:
**< add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Database=aaa;Data Source=bbb;User Id=ccc;Password=ddd;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>**

to 
< add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Database=aaa;Data Source=bbb;User Id=ccc;Password=ddd;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" **Max Pool Size=100; Min Pool Size=10**  />

Since actually I don't have defined any max and/or min pool size, I thought that, maybe, adding this 2 properties, the site will be more fast.

If I'll modify this row, I need to restart the server and/or recompile the ASP project to take this changes?

Finally, what is the maximum number allowed to Max Pool Size?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I highly doubt making these changes will speed your site up. If anything, it will probably slow it down. Rather than guessing indiscriminately at what might be slow, take the time to actually profile your site and see what's slow. Use a tool like MiniProfiler or simply add some logging around your processes that are running slow to isolate where the slow behavior is occurring.

Comment: Thanks for your support @mason, but do you know if I need to restart the server or recompile all to make changes updated? Thanks!

Comment: If you change the web.config file, the site will automatically restart. You do not need to do anything beyond modifying the file. Although as I pointed out, you're probably barking up the wrong tree anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are changing anything in web.config, your site will automatically restart and if you already logged in the application it will asks to relogin.

Also This doesn't going to help to improve the slowness of the application.
I think you should found the actual reason behind the slowness. definitely it would be something else. This might help you.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion @P Shah, this is what I would know, so when I'll save web.config it will reload itself without need to recompile.<br>I know that possibile causes are connection pool to db, applications problems but since I didn't receive any problems server side, I focused on connection string in web.config settings. In Db I checked and I found 200 user, connected at the same time, at maxium ( on a 5000 pool).